# proving convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I wish to prove that the improper integral:

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$$

converges.

This can be solved using integration by parts multiple times, but I'm sure there is an easier way.

I tried comparing this integral to $\frac{1}{x^n}$ for different $n$ but couldn't get to a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: asymptotically, $\log(x)$ grows much much slower than $x^{1/t}$  does for $t \in \Bbb N^*$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substiute $x=e^u$:
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\ln^5 x}{x^2}dx=\int_0^{\infty} u^5 e^{-u}\,du= \Gamma(6)=5!=120<\infty $$

Comment: Bit of typo here: $e^{-u}$ instead of $e^u$.

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: Definition of $\varGamma$-function.

Comment: I think my post has the proper definition? 
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: Now you are correct.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not change anything. Maybe there was a rendering problem on your side?

Comment: Maybe. My bad. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's fine, no problem!

Comment: Sorry but you did write it as $e^u$ which was wrong but @J.G. edited the answer within that span I guess

Answer (score 2):

For any $x\geq 0$ we have $\log(1+x)\leq x$ by concavity, hence
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^5(x)}{x^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z^6}{=}6\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{6^5 \log^5(z)}{z^{7}}\,dz = 6^6 \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^5(u+1)}{(u+1)^7}\,du $$
is bounded by 
$$6^6 \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^5}{(u+1)^7}\,du = 6^5. $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\ln^5(x)$ grows more slowly then $\sqrt{x}$.  Therefore, there exists an $x_0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, $\ln^5(x)< \sqrt{x}$.  We can write

$$\int_1^{\infty }\frac{\log^5(x)}{x^2}= \int_1^{x_0}\frac{\log^5(x)}{x^2}+\int_{x_0}^{\infty }\frac{\log^5(x)}{x^2}$$

$$\leq \int_1^{x_0}\frac{\log^5(x)}{x^2} + \int_{x_0}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2}$$

and we see that both terms are finite.

(Edit: if you are curious, $x_0=3.5\times 10^{15}$ suffices).